# TopoJSON: calculate scale and offset

Tags: python, math, geometry, geo

### Question:

**Given the absolute coordinates, how do I calculate the ideal value for the `scale` and `translate` for [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) topology transform?**

I want to go from this:

```
absolute = [
     [-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133],
     [-69.9009900990099, 12.417091709170947],
     [-69.97299729972997, 12.43445329884554],
     [-70.00900090009, 12.486538067869319],
     [-70.08100810081008, 12.538622836893097],
     [-70.08100810081008, 12.590707605916876],
     [-70.04500450045005, 12.608069195591469],
     [-70.00900090009, 12.55598442656769],
     [-69.93699369936994, 12.469176478194726],
     [-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133],
]
```

To this:

```
scale = [0.036003600360036005, 0.017361589674592462]
translate = [-180, -89.99892578124998]

relative = [[3058, 5901], [0, -2], [-2, 1], [-1, 3], [-2, 3], [0, 3], [1, 1], 
     [1, -3], [2, -5], [1, -1]]
```

I got the relative-to-absolute conversion working:

```
def arc_to_coordinates(topology, arc):
    scale = topology['transform']['scale']
    translate = topology['transform']['translate']

    x = 0
    y = 0
    coordinates = []

    for point in arc:
        x += point[0]
        y += point[1]
        coordinates.append([
            x * scale[0] + translate[0],
            y * scale[1] + translate[1] 
        ])

    return coordinates
```

Now I need to write the absolute-to-relative conversion. In order to to this, it is necessary to get the values for `scale` and `translate`, where I'm stuck.

### About topojson

topojson is a format for storing geographic features much like [geojson](http://www.geojson.org/).

In order to save space (among other tricks), the format uses relative integer offsets from the previous point. For example, this is the topojson file for Aruba:

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "transform": {
    "scale": [0.036003600360036005, 0.017361589674592462],
    "translate": [-180, -89.99892578124998]
  },
  "objects": {
    "aruba": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "arcs": [[0]],
      "id": 533
    }
  },
  "arcs": [
    [[3058, 5901], [0, -2], [-2, 1], [-1, 3], [-2, 3], [0, 3], [1, 1], 
     [1, -3], [2, -5], [1, -1]]
  ]
}
```

The same information as a GeoJSON feature looks like this:

```
{
    "type" : "Feature",
    "id" : 533,
    "properties" : {},
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [[
                 [-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133], 
                 [-69.9009900990099, 12.417091709170947], 
                 [-69.97299729972997, 12.43445329884554], 
                 [-70.00900090009, 12.486538067869319], 
                 [-70.08100810081008, 12.538622836893097], 
                 [-70.08100810081008, 12.590707605916876], 
                 [-70.04500450045005, 12.608069195591469], 
                 [-70.00900090009, 12.55598442656769], 
                 [-69.93699369936994, 12.469176478194726], 
                 [-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133]
            ]]
    }
}
```

It is easy to see how the former is more compact than the later. My absolute to relative function is working:

```
>>> arc_to_coordinates(topology, topology['arcs'][0])
[[-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133],
 [-69.9009900990099, 12.417091709170947],
 [-69.97299729972997, 12.43445329884554],
 [-70.00900090009, 12.486538067869319],
 [-70.08100810081008, 12.538622836893097],
 [-70.08100810081008, 12.590707605916876],
 [-70.04500450045005, 12.608069195591469],
 [-70.00900090009, 12.55598442656769],
 [-69.93699369936994, 12.469176478194726],
 [-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133]]
```

[update]

I believe the algorithm is somewhere [in this file](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/lib/topojson/topology.js), but I'm having a hard time translating the JS to Python. I love Mike's work, but sometimes his js looks like already minified... :-)

Comment: It looks like a math problem, when calculating `scale` and `translate`, is `arcs` list known? Or it is one of the targets to calculate?

Comment: `scale` and `translate` is used to transform absolute coordinates in the form `[ Point(-69.9009900990099, 12.451814888520133), Point(-69.9009900990099, 12.417091709170947), ...]` to a relative coordinates composed of small integers in the `arcs` array: `[Point(3058, 5901), Point(0, -2), ...]`.